# Custom Site Action Item not registring

Tags: custom-actions

I need to add a new action button in the Site Actions menu for my site.

If I do this without a custom WebControl, it works, using an Element.xml file. However, I cannot get this to work with a WebControl, as I need to place it just above the New Page item.

My Elements.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="BlueRing.SharePoint.NewProject"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    Rights="ManageSubwebs"
    ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    ControlClass="BlueRing.SharePoint.NewProject">    
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

My WebControl class

```
namespace BlueRing.SharePoint
{
    public class NewProject
        : WebControl
    {
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            MenuItemTemplate item = new MenuItemTemplate();
            item.Text = "New Project";
            item.Description = "Creates a new Project site";
            item.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/images/BlueRing/projecticon.png";
            item.MenuGroupId = 200;
            item.Sequence = 201;
            item.ClientOnClickScript = "removed for legibility";
            this.Controls.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

When I deploy my feature and activate it, the menu item is not visible. I followed [this](http://sharepointparadise.blogspot.com/2012/07/replace-new-page-menu-item-for.html) example to the T, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this, must be deployed via a Module and not a blank Elements.xml file.